# In memoriam: Bram Moolenaar

Tags: discussion

It looks like Bram [passed away a few days ago](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_announce/c/tWahca9zkt4).

Bram had been spending over 30 years on Vim; and not just "the occasional patch/bugfix", but significant amounts, and almost every single day for some years.

The number of people who spent that much time working on Open Source is very small, and the number of people who have spent that much time purely in their spare time is smaller still. In fact, I don't really know of anyone who even comes close to Bram.

The number of people who spent this much time volunteering for *anything* is very small.

Bram's effort on Vim was phenomenal and exceptional by any standard.

---

I only met Bram in person once, in 2014, [when he talked about Zimbu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O-QdG2X1Lw); at some point I must have given a bit of a skeptical look, and he promptly looked at me and asked "oh, you don't agree? Why not?" It was a nice talk with lots of "audience engagement" like this. We spent some time talking during the rest of the day and the next day; we discussed and joked about lots of things; I don't recall talking much about Vim: it just didn't come up. I found him a very friendly, warm, and likeable person.

Sven Guckes (who passed away last year) did organize a little "Ask Me Anything" type workshop with Bram, and I discovered Bram struggled remembering the ins-and-outs of some of the lesser used Vim features just as much as the rest of us

Comment: Thank you for posting this (I am away on vacation). I’m hoping to organize a little “celebration of life” over here. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm upvoting this only to show that I agreed with this text; not that I like his death.

Comment: @leeand00 this is not really the place for such conversation, which is already happening on GitHub and over email.